Request to solve the problem of retrieving firestore data using firebase functions with node.js
The authorUID value appears as undefined. I don't know how to get the userUID field value of the board collection. The boardID value is imported correctly, but in the process of inserting it into boardDoc and inserting boardData and authorUID in that order, the authorUID value appears as undefined, and I don't know why. Please tell me the solution.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Notify the board author when a comment is added to their post
exports.notifyAuthorOnComment = functions.firestore.document('board/{boardID}/comment/{commentID}').onCreate(async (snap, context) = \ > {
  const boardID = context.params.boardID;

  // Fetch the board document to get the author's UID
  const boardDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('board').doc(boardID).get();
  const boardData = boardDoc.data();
  const authorUID = boardData.userUID; // console.log ==\> undefined !!

  // Get the author's FCM token from the users collection
  const userDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('user').doc(authorUID).get();
  const userData = userDoc.data();
  const authorToken = userData.fcmToken;

  // Prepare the notification payload
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "new comment",
      body: `comment register.`
    },
    data: {
      boardID: boardID,
      commentID: context.params.commentID
    }
  };

  // Create the message object for the new method
  const message = {
    token: authorToken,
    notification: payload.notification,
    data: payload.data,
  };

  // Send the notification using the updated method
  await admin.messaging().send(message);
  return null;
});

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
[enter image description here][4]

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/AJREqwh8.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/XWZEmH8c.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/oJMeL3CA.png
  [4]: https://i.sstatic.net/CIIf0Rrk.jpg


We can't see your database data, so there is no way for us to know why authorUID is undefined.  Please edit the question to show the relevant document you're trying to read.  A screenshot of the console might help.  You should ensure that your code is reading the same document ID as you are showing in your question.

please add console.log to boardData and see if  userUID is present

I show the firestore data structure and error log as an image file. I would like to know the solution.

The boardID in the first document doesn't match the document ID that you're trying to read right after that.  You're reading a document that just doesn't exist.

Can you tell me how to fix it?

You should make sure you write the correct values into your documents.  We can't see how you're doing that.

I understand. thank you.
